# angular image upload validation message issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I am using angular image upload plugin. I want to show `ngf-pattern` error message if user upload invalid file type. but problem is another error message shows (ng-required message). how to stop `ng-required` message. I am doing validation using angular-auto-validate plugin.

my code

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="file.nicCopy" name="nicCopy" ngf-pattern="'.jpg,.jpeg,.png'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" ng-required="!customerDetails.isPending && (customerDetails.customerType.description | uppercase) == 'INDIVIDUAL' && (!customerDetails.filepathnic || customerDetails.filepathnic == 'null')" ngf-resize="{width: 800, height: 600}" ngf-resize-if="$width > 800 || $height > 600" class="form-control" />
  <!--<input type="file"  file-model="myFile"  class="form-control"/></div>   ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" -->
  <img ngf-thumbnail="file.nicCopy" ngf-size="{width: 100, height: 100, quality: 0.9} ">

  <div ng-if="customerForm.nicCopy.$error.pattern" class="error-msg">Invalid File Format </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add condition like '' ng-if="customerForm.nicCopy.$error.pattern && !customerForm.nicCopy.$error.required " "'

Comment: can u explain more ..?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the file extension can be done via simple Javascript instead of going with plugins.

```
var extension = filename.split(".").pop();
```

Similarly try using DOM for picking up such properties for validation. Probably make your own function to make it re-usable.